# Ajax beforeSend issue only on chrome browser when async: false

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I made one small ajax function which returns json object received from server, I checked this function on firefox, operamini, works fine and during posting data to server I am able to see spinner image, but incase of google chrome I can't see spinner while posting, when `async` is `false`, if I make `async : true`, I can see spinner.

Can someone tell me solution for same, all functions in my script are working fine, except spinner only on chrome.

Any more things I can add to show spinner for chrome to existing function ? The only way left for me is to modify the function, because this function is called in many other functions in my script which is very long too.. I will be happy if anyone can provide me alternate solution.

**Chrome : Version 28.0.1500.71 Ubuntu 12.04 (28.0.1500.71-0ubuntu1.12.04.1)**

**jQuery v2.1.3**

**This is my function**

```
function _get_data(options) {
      var result={};
      $.ajax({
              url   : options.url,
              async : false,  
              cache : false,
              data  : options.data,
          beforeSend: function() {
                       $(options.before.element).html(options.before.html);
              },
             method : "POST",
           dataType : "json",
             success:function(data) {
                       result = data; 
              }
            });
     return result;
  }
```

**This is how I call it**

```
  var my_data = _get_data({ 
                url    :'http://dba.org/test',
                before : { 
                        element : "#loading", 
                        html    : '<img class="loader" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhE ... somemore"/>' 
                     },
                data   : { firefox : true, chrome : false } 
            });
```

If anyone here got solution already please share

Thanks in advance,

**Wish You Happy New Year In Advance..**

Comment: I'm surprised it works on the other browsers. There shouldn't be any rendering while a synchronous function is running.

Comment: Why do you send true if firefox and false if chrome?

Comment: its just sample data

Comment: @Barmar : I really don't know why, this is happening...

Comment: Maybe if you make the ajax call after DOM ready in chrome it can work

Comment: @Barmar : As soon as I click on my navigation menu, I can see loader in some div ( firefox ), but till ajax success, I can't click / select any other option this means its sync right ? yes, but don't know why I can't see spinner incase of chrome...

Comment: Because Chrome doesn't let the renderer run until all Javascript finishes.

Comment: @Barmar : any async solution ? @pabillitoo : is it like this -->  `$(document).ready(function(){ });` ? if so I am already using like this

Comment: If you do it async there shouldn't be a problem. You should avoid using synchronous AJAX.

Comment: @Barmar: Sir My script is too long.. even all functions works fine on chrome except this beforeSend spinner.. please help me..

Comment: It's just the way it is. Synchronous AJAX blocks the browser, nothing happens while it's waiting.

Comment: @Barmar : can you tell me, if I use `$(options.before.element).html(options.before.html);` before `$.ajax({...})` is still not working why ? any idea ?

Comment: check if .html is cross-browser or $(options.before.element).html(options.before.html) works in chrome console

Comment: @pabliiitoo : Sorry I didn't get u

Comment: check if `$("#loading").html('<img class="loader" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhE ... somemore"/>' 
)` works in chrome console

Comment: @pabliiitoo : Ok I will try now

Comment: @pabliiitoo : Yes works fine no issue;

Comment: Are you making the ajax call to another domain?

Comment: Chrome doesn't permit cross browser Ajax calls try the same with this in bash: chromium-browser --disable-web-security

Comment: Return expected results here http://jsfiddle.net/04qpcLyo/1/ ?

Comment: Did you find a solution please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)